# Spring RestService - target invocation exception

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to invoke a service using Spring's `RestOperations` class, but am getting a target invocation exception on the line where it invokes `rest.getForObject`. This is the method where the exception gets thrown:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

public List<INorcaSummarySystemDTO> getNorcaSummaryBySystem(String systemName, Date fromDate){
    
    List<INorcaSummarySystemDTO> norcaSummarySystem = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        
            URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(configuration.getDacqUrl() + 
                    "/fa/api/v1/facility/1/norcasummarysystem")
                    .build().toUri();
            NorcaSummarySystemDTO[] list = rest.getForObject(uri.toString(), NorcaSummarySystemDTO[].class);
            norcaSummarySystem = Arrays.asList(list);
    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        if (LOG.isErrorEnabled()) {
            LOG.error("Exception while getting Norca summary system. Error: {}", e.getMessage());
            LOG.trace(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    return norcaSummarySystem;
}
```

The URI that it's invoking works when I call it from postman:

```
http://localhost:8181/fa/api/v1/facility/1/norcasummarysystem
```

Here's a picture of it in the debugger:

[image: url in rest call]

I'm modeling the call from another class which does the same thing, i.e. uses the rest client to return a list array of DTOs, based on the two lines in particular:

```
BarcodeDataDTO[] barcodeData = restClient.getForObject(uri.toString(), BarcodeDataDTO[].class);
dacqBarcodeDataDTOS = Arrays.asList(barcodeData);
```

This is the full method from that class:

```
List<BarcodeDataDTO> dacqBarcodeDataDTOS;
try {
    URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder
            .fromUriString(
                    servicesConfiguration.getDacqUrl() +API_V1_PATH + Constants.URI_FACILITY +
                    facility.getFacilityName() + Constants.URI_SYSTEM + 
                    URLEncoder.encode(system.getSystemName(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8) + 
                    Constants.URI_OBJECT + objectId + Constants.URI_BARCODES)
            .queryParam(Constants.SCAN_TIME, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.format(scanTime)).build().toUri();

    BarcodeDataDTO[] barcodeData = restClient.getForObject(uri.toString(), BarcodeDataDTO[].class);
    dacqBarcodeDataDTOS = Arrays.asList(barcodeData);
} catch (RestClientException restException) {
    LOGGER.error(restException.getMessage(), restException);
    return Collections.emptyList();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new ConnectionFailureException(
            "Fail to fetch barcode data from data aquisition layer. The exception is: " + e);
}
```

This is the code for the RestController being invoked:

```
package com.sick.ilcore.dacq.controller;



/**
 * <p>NorcaSummaryController class.</p>
 *
 */
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping(CommonConstants.API_V1 + "/facility/{facilityName}")
public class NorcaSummaryController {
    
    @Autowired
    private IBarcodeDataService barcodedataService;

    /**
     *
     * @param system name 
     * @param fromDate - optional from date in yyyy-MM-dd format 
     *
     * @return NORCA totals by system  
     */


    @GetMapping(value = "/norcasummarysystem")
    private List<INorcaSummarySystemDTO> getNorcaSummaryBySystem(
            @RequestParam("systemName") Optional<String> systemName,
            @RequestParam("fromDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Optional<Date> fromDate) {
            
        
        String systemNameVal = null;
        if (systemName.isPresent()) {
            systemNameVal =  systemName.get();          
        }
        else {
            systemNameVal = "all";
        }
        Date fromDateVal = DACQUtils.calcFromDateVal(fromDate);
        
        List<INorcaSummarySystemDTO> norcaList = barcodedataService.getNorcaSummaryBySystem(systemNameVal, fromDateVal);
        return norcaList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be a jackson exception that showed up after a couple of hours. A quick google revealed that I had to add a default constructor to the DTOs.